# How would I create an array that holds multiple sprites and positions them on the screen?

Tags: arrays, scala, arraylist, foreach

I am making a version of brick breaker/breakout using Scala and FANG (fangengine.org).  I want to have 3 rows of bricks, each with 8 bricks in each row.  How would I create an array that can hold all these bricks and then how would I position the bricks on the screen?

I was able to create one brick, but I have no idea how to make multiple and put them into an array:

```
  var brick: RectangleSprite = new RectangleSprite(2,1)
```

The(2,1) is the size ratio of the rectangle.

Could the positioning be done with a for loop?  How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
val bricks = for(i<-0 until 10) yield new RectangleSprite(i,i)
```